# Auto generating a solidity based smart contracts

Tags: solidity, contract-development, automate

I have recently built a Custom UI and integrated it into a jupyterlab notebook environment. This UI helps the data owners define the sharing policies on the basis of the carefully chosen constraints, which are saved in a MongoDB database. Now, I want to build an API that takes these saved values and auto-generates the solidity smart contract. What are the best practices and approaches to achieve this?? Are there any good resources available to learn about auto-generation of smart contracts?

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to this community.

You can create a script with web3.js (https://docs.infura.io/tutorials/ethereum/deploy-a-contract-using-web3.js?q=filter) and then you can extract the constant part of the code and make them as arguments. If you have a regular Solidity code like ERC20, I think you don't have hard work to do but if not, maybe you need to create a way to make *.Sol contract code automatically. and please do all these things in testnet network before mainnet (I think you know that but I should say that).